# How to reinstall Steam on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, steam, reinstalling

I have recently installed Steam on my PC (Ubuntu 16.04). I have up until recently only ever used windows and in windows you can 'unpin' applications from the start page. I tried to do something similar here and remove the Steam icon from my dash by using the command:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop
```

but this seemed to also delete the application itself (or at least prevent me from running it). I tried several computer searches to try and find where Steam was on my hard-drive, but all were unsuccessful. In the end I removed Steam using the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge steam
```

and then cleaned up using:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

but when I try to install Steam now, all that I get is

```
sudo apt-get install steam
[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  steam:i386
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 138 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/875 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,664 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package steam:i386.
(Reading database ... 359072 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../steam_1%3a1.0.0.48-1ubuntu4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking steam:i386 (1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu4) ...
Replaced by files in installed package steam-launcher (1.0.0.54) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up steam:i386 (1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu4) ...
```

and nothing else happens. What should I do?

P.S. I have also tried installing Steam from the website and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Just for future reference: The first action you took didn't remove the application, just the desktop/menu shortcut.

Comment: This is a valuable clue: `Replaced by files in installed package steam-launcher (1.0.0.54)` How did you install steam the first time?  I have a working `steam` installation, and I don't have a `steam-launcher` package.  I can't find it in the standard repos.

Comment: As a minimum, looks like you should purge `steam-launcher`.

Comment: The first time I just installed Steam from the website. I shall try what you suggested about purging steam-launcher.

Comment: So I purged steam-installer like you suggested and then reinstalled from the website and so far, so good. Thanks Organic Marble! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome!  I shall post my suggestion as an answer and if it helped you, you can accept it there.

Comment: How do I accept it? sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie.

Comment: No problem, thanks for asking. Just click on the gray check mark beside the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valuable clue: `Replaced by files in installed package steam-launcher (1.0.0.54)` How did you install steam the first time? I have a working `steam` installation, and I don't have a `steam-launcher` package. I can't find it in the standard repos.

As a minimum, looks like you should purge `steam-launcher` and then try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

Just type sudo apt-get remove steam

If sudo apt-get remove steam doesn't work, you may skip this step.

Next, type in sudo apt-get purge steam

Then install Steam.deb from the steam website!

Hope this worked out!

Comment: Does this work for anything? Or is it specific for Steam?

Comment: I tried to install the `steam.deb` from the official website on Debian 12, but it can not be even opened. The steam windows were blinking indefinitely.